# Most profitable trade routes

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag, assassins-creed-4-kenways-fleet

I now have access to 'Kenways Fleet' and am busy sending out ships to do trade missions. However most of the routes seem to top out at about 700R in 4 minutes.

Are there any more profitable trade routes? Do these routes require certain types of ship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Bissau, Cape Verde**
Giant Appetites – 3,400R
Meet the Tributes II – 3,400R

**Cape Town, South Africa**
Table Bay’s Luck – 5,000R
New Economic Hub – 5,200R

**London, North West Europe**
A New Cathedral – 3,800R
The Poet – 3,500R
The Great Plague – 3,500R

**Galway, North West Europe**
A Long Voyage – 3,200R

**Gibraltar, Mediterranean Sea**
Great Reputation I – 3,200R
Being Mad – 3,200R

**Barcelona, Mediterranean Sea**
Great Reputation II – 3,700R
The Catalans – 3,800R
The Smokers – 3,700R

**Marseille, Mediterranean Sea**
Great Reputation III – 5,200R
A New Medicine – 5,200R

Ref: http://www.tradeindetectives.com/blog/how-to-earn-the-most-money-in-kenways-fleet/

Answer (score 5):

As you progress with the trade routes other locations open up.  They become more and more profitable as you continue to open more locations.  The more profitable locations do require larger ships(more cargo space) like the Man o' War.  These more profitable routes also take more time though.

For a list of better ship locations, names of other Trade Missions and tips check the link:[Kenway Fleet Guide](http://segmentnext.com/2013/11/01/assassins-creed-4-kenways-fleet-guide-trading-missions-and-ships/)

Comment: It's worth noting that the linked guide is only really helpful for hunting specific ships and contains nothing on the profit involved in specific trade routes.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this issue mid game as well. Scrolling through all the missions and comparing them is a pain in the neck. So I made [a spreadsheet ranking the best missions for each cargo size](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-bZSYOf4K6Jb4PKmw_1ZD20iWKPqm5xY4HyJpbryQqg/edit?usp=sharing). Many of the missions that "perfectly" fit that cargo size are highlighted in the sheet.

Below are the top missions for each cargo size by return. Notice that many of them are smaller "loads" - they pay better than the larger ones. The "New Economic Hub" is the most profitable mission and only requires 30 cargo. It's worth noting that many missions have other rewards not reflected in the spreadsheet, and most need to be unlocked by doing other missions first.

- Cargo size 15:

  - Portugal: Do No Harm - 1700
  - Bay of Biscay: Sweet Broth - 1500
  - South Atlantic: Diplomacy III - 1300
- Cargo Size 20:

  - Portugal: Do No Harm - 1700
  - Bay of Biscay: A Sweet Journey - 1600
  - Bay of Biscay: Sweet Broth - 1500
- Cargo Size 25:

  - Portugal: Do No Harm - 1700
  - Bay of Biscay: A Sweet Journey - 1600
  - Bay of Biscay: Sweet Broth - 1500
- Cargo Size 30:

  - South Africa: New Economic Hub - 5200
  - Mediterranean Sea: The Catalans - 3800
  - South Africa: Door to Europe - 2400
- Cargo Size 35:

  - South Africa: New Economic Hub - 5200
  - Mediterranean Sea: The Catalans - 3800
  - South Africa: Door to Europe - 2400
- Cargo Size 40:

  - South Africa: New Economic Hub - 5200
  - South Africa: Table Bay's Luck - 5000
  - Mediterranean Sea: The Catalans - 3800
- Cargo Size 50:

  - South Africa: New Economic Hub - 5200
  - Mediterranean Sea: A New Medicine - 5200
  - South Africa: Table Bay's Luck - 5000
- Cargo Size 60:

  - South Africa: New Economic Hub - 5200
  - Mediterranean Sea: A New Medicine - 5200
  - South Africa: Table Bay's Luck - 5000
- Cargo Size 70:

  - South Africa: New Economic Hub - 5200
  - Mediterranean Sea: A New Medicine - 5200
  - South Africa: Table Bay's Luck - 5000
- Cargo Size 80:

  - South Africa: New Economic Hub - 5200
  - Mediterranean Sea: Great Reputation III - 5200
  - Mediterranean Sea: A New Medicine - 5200
- Cargo Size 90:

  - South Africa: New Economic Hub - 5200
  - Mediterranean Sea: Great Reputation III - 5200
  - Mediterranean Sea: A New Medicine - 5200

If someone finds a good source listing the cities for each mission, I'll add that to the spreadsheet and possibly note the requirements.